# при запуске кода под надписью "что ты хочешь открыть?(phisics, ..., ...)?:" появляеться "None". Подскажитепожалуйста, как убрать "None"

Tags: python

```
def phisics():

    what = input("Что ты хочешь узнать? (давление, скорость, сила тяжести, плотность):")

    if what == "давление":
        F = float( input("сила(H): "))
        S = float( input("площадь(m): "))
        otvet = F / S

    elif what == "скорость":
        put = float( input("путь(m): "))
        time = float( input("время(c): "))
        otvet = put / time

    elif what == "сила тяжести":
        m = float( input("масса(кг): "))
        g = float( input("ускорение свободного падения(H/кг): "))
        otvet = m * g

    elif what == "плотность":
        m = float( input("масса(кг): "))
        V = float( input("обьем(m в кубе): "))
        otvet = m / V

    print( otvet )

    (input("нажмите \"Enter\" что бы закрыть программу"))

what = input(print("что ты хочешь открыть?(phisics, ..., ...)?: "))

if what == "phisics":
    phisics()
```

Comment: Что значит "Как убрать None при вводе?"?

Comment: когда запускаю программу под надписью "что ты хочешь открыть?(phisics, ..., ...)?:" появляется None

Comment: Ну так вы здесь `input(print("что ты хочешь открыть?(phisics, ..., ...)?: "))` пишете "что ты хочешь открыть?(phisics, ..., ...)?: ", а потом то, что возвращает `input()`, то есть `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простo замените строку

```
what = input(print("что ты хочешь открыть?(phisics, ..., ...)?: "))
```

на

```
what = input("что ты хочешь открыть?(phisics, ..., ...)?: ")
```

Проблема в том, что функция print ничего не возвращает